# How do i display a loading text while requesting httpget?

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, .net-core

I am trying to show a simple loading text message inside modal until data is not received from JQuery get request.

My Button

```
//using foreach loop (var x in Model)
<a id="@x.Id" onclick="editStudent(this.id)" > </a>
```

My Modal

```
              <div id="editDetailModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <!-- Modal content-->
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>EDIT STUDENT DETAILS</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body dash-form">
                                 
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

This method calls EditStudent with studentId, during the first request, modal freezes and display data after getting, but when i click edit button second times, it displays the same previous data and after getting data in second request it replaces previous data with new data.

```
  function editStudent(id) {
  {
         $.get("@Url.Action("EditStudent","Student")/" + id,
             function (data) {
             $('.modal-body').html(data);
                 
         });
              $("#editDetailModal").modal("show");

           
  }
```

In Controller

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult EditStudent(int id)
        {
            var student = _context.Students.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            return PartialView("_EditStudent", student);
        }
```

Comment: Why is your Controller waiting 2 seconds arbitrarily?

Comment: just checking to see, it will take 2 second anyway because there are other code inside the method.

Comment: You should probably fire them asynchronously then and await their results.  Since you're using JQuery (based on tags) just fill whatever element you need with a loading GIF via beforeSend in an AJAX call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a loading text inside your modal body, and replace it when data are fetched.

```
function editStudent(id) {
{
   //Here add a text before loading
   $('.modal-body').empty().html("<h2>Data loading...</h2>");
     
   $.get("@Url.Action("EditStudent","Student")/" + id,
         function (data) {
         $('.modal-body').html(data);
             
     });
          $("#editDetailModal").modal("show");       
}
```